# Unix powerful image processing tool

Tags: unix, image-processing

I am looking for a powerful image processor tool, that can resize large image.
I have few 10GB images, currently in .png, .jpeg and .tiff format.
I want to perform simple image processing operation such as resize operation to make it smaller using a unix computer, purely command line.

I have tried ImageMagick but it freezes the computer. Is there other tool that can handle image with such big size?

thanks,

Comment: This is oft-topic for 2 reasons: 1. It's not about programming; 2. It's a request for a tool. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Off-topic, but `vips` will do it... http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend GIMP, the GNU Image Manipulation Program `http://www.gimp.org/`

Comment: Does GIMP handle large images (i.e. 10 GB)?   The OP has these kinds of images.  This isn't a slapdown of your post.... I'm actually genuinely curious if GIMP can handle large image files.